# Add a ressource to multiple phases (presync and deploy) in argoCd

Tags: argocd

In ArgoCd we work intesively with the the preSync phase to setup and init the environment.
No it happens that e.g. we need certain secrets and config maps indentically in both the preSync phase and in the sync phase.
For this we currently define the same ressource twice, soley once with the preSync hook annotation.
This clutters up the configuration and makes it hard to read an understand, especially when we need to pass them to a child chart.

Is it possible to register a ressource for multiple phases, so I don't need to define the ressource for each phase?

Comment: your terminology is a bit all over the place, but you should create the secret/configMap in the PreSync "hook", and do not clean it up as a part of the hook completion. This will persist the secret. If this becomes too much, have another application manage secrets and configs.